# Conflict between jQuery.load(), jQuery.focus(), and link tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

## Back-story

I am creating a web application in which individual pages are "loaded" via the jQuery [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function. Originally the loaded page was a single file, but as it got longer I decided to split it into a .html file, a .css file, and a .js file.

Strangely, a single design flaw arose surrounding an element that was positioned using percentage values within the `css`. To see if I modified the styling while I moved, I replace the `style` tag (omitting the `link` tag instead) and it worked fine. Back and fourth a few times and I learned it was strictly occurring only when I used `link` tags rather than embedding it via `style` tags.

I wanted to use `link` tags, so I tried to narrow the problem down. After a while of fiddling, I traced it down to the .js file, specifically a usage of the `.focus` function on `$(document).ready`. If I comment out the `.focus`, everything works fine. Uncomment, and it breaks.

This appears to only happen in Chrome. It doesn't occur in FF26 or IE11.

## Example

[A fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Chakra/SPCy4/)

Note that the problem only occurs in Chrome and that caching must be disabled. As Chrome's temporary cache disable doesn't extend into iframes of iframes, a [direct result](http://jsfiddle.net/Chakra/SPCy4/show/) is easier to work with.

Comment: please move your example to jsfiddle

Comment: If you're loading the `input` tag via `.load`, you won't be able to focus it on `document.ready`. You need to add a success callback function to the `.load` event and focus the tag in there.

Comment: You also can't run scripts linked from `portal.html` via `.load`. You must load and run those external scripts explicitly using `.getScript()`

Comment: @LorDex I tried creating a fiddle, but since it has so many dependencies, I was having a lot of problems. I got it working somewhat, but the .css is cached, which essentially fixes the problem.

@Blazemonger [`.load()`'s documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/#script-execution) strictly states scripts are executed. The document.ready probably doesn't actually execute when ready, but using `.load`'s second parameter doesn't wait until the script is executed.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provides a callback function when the .load() method has completed and the DOM has been updated. This is where you would want to operate on elements that have been inserted from your external url.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#content').load('html/portal.html', function() {
            //now i can operate on elements loaded from html/portal.html
            //they have been inserted into the DOM
            $('input#input').focus();
        })
    });
</script>
```

As far as references to the link element, if you want to dynamically load a stylesheet from an external url using javascript you can employ a javascript function something like this:

```
//load deferred stylesheets 
function loadStyleSheet(src) {
    if (document.createStyleSheet) {
        document.createStyleSheet(src);
    } else {
        $("head").append($("<link rel='stylesheet' href='"+src+"' type='text/css' media='screen' />"));
    }
}
```

If you want to load an external javascript file you can use jQuery.getScript():

```
jQuery.getScript('/js/external.js');
```

So putting all of this together, if you want to load some content from an external resource, insert it into the DOM and the load an external stylesheet and an external javascript resource you could do so as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //function to load a deferred stylesheets 
            var loadStyleSheet = function(src) {
                if (document.createStyleSheet) {
                    document.createStyleSheet(src);
                } else {
                    $("head").append($("<link rel='stylesheet' href='"+src+"' type='text/css' media='screen' />"));
                }
            }

            $('#someWrapper').load('external-url.html #someWrapper > *', function() {
                loadStyleSheet('/css/external.css');
                jQuery.getScript('/js/external.js');
            })
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="someWrapper">
        <!-- external content is loaded here -->
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: While this is no doubt better practice than using the `document.ready`, it doesn't fix the strange UI problem when using .focus(). Perhaps I can better the fiddle, though.

Comment: Oh sorry -- what I meant is that the issue with .focus() is caused by calling it before the content is loaded into the DOM. If you call it inside the .load() callback as illustrated in this example it should fix your issue.

Comment: The element is focused, though. I updated the fiddle, and it, again, fails (but fixes after the .css is cached). http://jsfiddle.net/Chakra/2Xada/14/ The only problem is that the elements are positioned incorrectly.

Comment: I always get the same result in the fiddle. What do you see changing between your first and second (cached) result and what OS/browser are you testing in?

Comment: I didn't capture it in the fiddle (but I can if you want), but images of the first and second states are shown in a recent edit. http://imgur.com/HHY0mte,twOk5Gn. I just tested it in FF and the bug doesn't appear. Only in Chrome 31 (Win8).

Comment: OK I did see the issue in Chrome on mac but it looks like it was just a js fiddle issue. In fiddles you load external resources like your CSS file using the "External Resources" tab on the side. I switched the CSS over there and I don't seem to catch the issue anymore. Is it fixed for you as well? http://jsfiddle.net/davemaple/2Xada/17/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45157/discussion-between-vox-and-dave-maple)